# Puppeteer promisifying an event, is this proper event control flow?

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the name of a downloaded file while using puppeteer and I have the following set up, but I'm wondering how best to `removeListener` for `page.on('response', ...`, as I want to be able to set and unset this event each time a file is downloaded:

```
async (page) => {
  const form = await page.$('#selector');
  const [filename] = await Promise.all([
    getFileNamePromise(page),
    form.evaluate(form => form.submit())
  ]) 
  return filename;
};

function getFileNamePromise(page) {
  return new Promise (resolve => {
    page.on('response', response => {
      const disposition = response.headers()['content-disposition'];

      if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
          resolve(matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '')) ;
        }
      }
    })
  });
}
```

I'm also curious if this is going to be susceptible to a race condition where the file is downloaded before the event listener is loaded?

Comment: Are you referring to removing the listener for `page.on('response'...`?

Comment: @LonnieBest yes - I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Go [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-class-page) in the documentation.

After the first code example is says:

> The Page class emits various events (described below) which can be
>   handled using any of Node's native EventEmitter methods, such as on,
>   once or removeListener.

Later it says this, followed by a code example:

> To unsubscribe from events use the removeListener method:

```
function logRequest(interceptedRequest) {
  console.log('A request was made:', interceptedRequest.url());
}
page.on('request', logRequest);
// Sometime later...
page.removeListener('request', logRequest);
```

So I'm assuming you could just follow suit with something like `page.removeListener('response'...`.

As for the race condition portion of your question, I don't have enough experience with Puppeteer to give you an authoritative answer. To me, it seems that, you'd always be able to set the event listener faster than the response can occur, because that code that sets the event listener will be in the event-loop already when the response is added to the Event Queue. However, I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up adding the removeListener as part of the logic tied to resolving the promise. As follows:

```
page.on('response', function getFileNameFromRequest(response) {
  //check for "Content-Disposition" ?
  const disposition = response.headers()['content-disposition'];

  if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
    if (matches != null && matches[1]) { 
      resolve(matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, ''));
      page.removeListener("response", getFileNameFromRequest);
    }
  }
});
```